# VerifyError when creating an instance of XSSFWorkbook

Tags: android, excel, apache-poi

I am using poi-3.7.jar.

I am getting

```
java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
```

When I am trying to read XSSFWorkbook.

```
Workbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(myInput);
```

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Apache POI Components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)

> *Component* - *Description* - *Artifact*
>
> XSSF - Excel XLSX - poi-ooxml

In order to be able to use XSSF, you need *both* the poi jar *and* the poi-ooxml jar, plus their respective dependencies (as detailed on the [components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)). The main poi jar doesn't have XSSF and friends in it.

Additionally, POI 3.7 is rather old, you'll really want to upgrade to a newer version (eg 3.10.1 or 3.11 beta 2, as of writing)